# Rebuild Github repository tree structure

Tags: php, tree, github-api

With the help of the Github API in PHP, i'm trying to show on my webpage the complete structure of selected repos. By structure, I mean directory/subdirectories and associated files:

```
dir1
-subdir1-1
--file1
--file2
-subdir1-2
--subdir1-3
--file1
--file2
--file3
dir2
[...]
```

With this endpoint I can grab all required informations:
`https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo-name/git/trees/HEAD:?recursive=1`

For example, with one repo, I have the following result:

```
{
  "sha": "d1dec6e8910b9e00370570caa5e5dedd930ebe9e",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/DivineOmega/DO-File-Cache/git/trees/d1dec6e8910b9e00370570caa5e5dedd930ebe9e",
  "tree": [
    {
      "path": ".coveralls.yml",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "dd9e7b806675d92983e7e3a1b504c18122b848c2",
      "size": 106,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/DivineOmega/DO-File-Cache/git/blobs/dd9e7b806675d92983e7e3a1b504c18122b848c2"
    },
    {
      "path": ".gitignore",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "162bf51a335abe6a8905092f564fcafa154c197b",
      "size": 39,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/DivineOmega/DO-File-Cache/git/blobs/162bf51a335abe6a8905092f564fcafa154c197b"
    },
    {
      "path": ".travis.yml",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "161ea29552f271918aaa24dfaa7f57c8746993aa",
      "size": 269,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/DivineOmega/DO-File-Cache/git/blobs/161ea29552f271918aaa24dfaa7f57c8746993aa"
    },
    {
      "path": "LICENSE",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "341c30bda4457610db4829294e5d7e526d4c835b",
      "size": 7652,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/DivineOmega/DO-File-Cache/git/blobs/341c30bda4457610db4829294e5d7e526d4c835b"
    },
    {
      "path": "README.md",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "f7b2da564b87dc7beaad260eb1c9674aae3161d8",
      "size": 4760,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/DivineOmega/DO-File-Cache/git/blobs/f7b2da564b87dc7beaad260eb1c9674aae3161d8"
    },
    {
      "path": "composer.json",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "e83099ae43f1573493ff8fb967c0f8012f72dc0a",
      "size": 859,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/DivineOmega/DO-File-Cache/git/blobs/e83099ae43f1573493ff8fb967c0f8012f72dc0a"
    },
    {
      "path": "phpunit.xml",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "0da3f08a6b4dd708f4c635d7647ab63c2926fb1f",
      "size": 931,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/DivineOmega/DO-File-Cache/git/blobs/0da3f08a6b4dd708f4c635d7647ab63c2926fb1f"
    },
    {
      "path": "src",
      "mode": "040000",
      "type": "tree",
      "sha": "e1a3d6a8d9fa88e83a5b7e97c324abf205445dce",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/DivineOmega/DO-File-Cache/git/trees/e1a3d6a8d9fa88e83a5b7e97c324abf205445dce"
    },
    {
      "path": "src/DOFileCache.php",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "77d091424bd9cb62359339bc7bc68b6eacfe91c7",
      "size": 8955,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/DivineOmega/DO-File-Cache/git/blobs/77d091424bd9cb62359339bc7bc68b6eacfe91c7"
    },
    {
      "path": "tests",
      "mode": "040000",
      "type": "tree",
      "sha": "19a801f7cdd01e9fb38d91a282a763b099590307",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/DivineOmega/DO-File-Cache/git/trees/19a801f7cdd01e9fb38d91a282a763b099590307"
    },
    {
      "path": "tests/Functional",
      "mode": "040000",
      "type": "tree",
      "sha": "65c076e8413e0a21876c3510e018f646b8712df9",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/DivineOmega/DO-File-Cache/git/trees/65c076e8413e0a21876c3510e018f646b8712df9"
    },
    {
      "path": "tests/Functional/CacheStorageAndRetrievalTest.php",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "09e7e3128dc316886ba19a14a4b4e0e43375dc78",
      "size": 2713,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/DivineOmega/DO-File-Cache/git/blobs/09e7e3128dc316886ba19a14a4b4e0e43375dc78"
    },
    {
      "path": "tests/Unit",
      "mode": "040000",
      "type": "tree",
      "sha": "30d84ac9006176312c78787092618736d9258119",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/DivineOmega/DO-File-Cache/git/trees/30d84ac9006176312c78787092618736d9258119"
    },
    {
      "path": "tests/Unit/.keep",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391",
      "size": 0,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/DivineOmega/DO-File-Cache/git/blobs/e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391"
    },
    {
      "path": "tests/Unit/BasicTest.php",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "b459c228dab0d37f23bcaf20619eecfbacda6f42",
      "size": 3933,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/DivineOmega/DO-File-Cache/git/blobs/b459c228dab0d37f23bcaf20619eecfbacda6f42"
    }
  ],
  "truncated": false
}
```

Files are tagged as "blob" and directories as "tree" `type`.
My problem is coming from `path` informations. It shows the path of the object. How can I show each object (files and subdirectories) in his parent directory, recursively?

**[EDIT 1]**
My actual PHP code:

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    if ($trees['tree'][$i]['type'] == 'tree'){ //directory
        $dirs .= '<span class="material-icons">folder</span> ' . $trees['tree'][$i]['path'] . '<br>';
    }
    if ($trees['tree'][$i]['type'] == 'blob'){ //file
        $files .= '<span class="material-icons">text_snippet</span> ' . $trees['tree'][$i]['path'] . '<br>';
    }
}
echo $dirs . $files;
```

It only shows a flat structure (dir and subdir at top level) but I don't know how to achieve the desired format structure.

Thank you for your precious help!

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, your best attempt(code). You might be closer to a solution than you think.  What does not work as expected? Please read [ask]!

Comment: Hi berend, you're right! I've forgotten to embed my code. But i'm far from the result. I've spent 2 days in searching before asking for some help here.